# Return unique nodes in Cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a query that can return a potentially huge number of rows. It is extremely critical that it is as fast as possible.

My current query shows doubling nodes because of filter polylines how do I do so that I can display the `n.NAME` that will be distinct?

PS : PS: if I delete : -->  `extract(n in segments | n.ORIGIN_POLYLINE) as polylines,`  so i have the good result but I would like to leave the polylines with unique nodes  (see pictures :1 and 2)

Here is my query:

```
MATCH (p:Polyline_ROMANIA)-[:CONTAINS_ROMANIA]->(n:Point_ROMANIA) 
WHERE p.ID_POLYLINE='9141'
WITH head(COLLECT(n)) as start
MATCH c=(start)<-[:SEGMENT_ROMANIA*0..]-(pt1:Point_ROMANIA)<-[:CONNECTED_ROMANIA]-(e:Establishment_ROMANIA) 
WITH 2 * 6371 * asin(sqrt(haversin(radians(toFloat(e.Y) - toFloat(start.Y))) + cos(radians(toFloat(e.Y)))* cos(radians(toFloat(start.Y)))* haversin(radians(toFloat(e.X) - toFloat(start.X))))) AS distance, e, c 
WHERE  distance <= 5000
WITH Distinct e, filter(n in rels(c) where n.ORIGIN_POLYLINE IS NOT NULL) AS segments, distance 
RETURN e as nodes, extract(n in segments | n.ORIGIN_POLYLINE) as polylines, distance
```

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEXSq.png)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFs0C.png)